# Clearing a form inputs except some controls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a panel named pBody and I can clear its controls by using these codes.
clear all textboxes, uncheck radio buttons and checkboxes:

```
$('#pBody input').val('');
```

clear only textboxes:

```
$("#pBody").find("input[type=text]").val('');
```

or

```
$("#pBody").find("input:text").val('');
```

But after clicking clear button I want make some radio buttons checked, for example first radio buttons in the group.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can just apply classes to the radio buttons and then apply `:not` in the selector for getting the rest of the controls and do the further processing

Comment: Can you show that in the code?

Comment: `$("input:not(.test)").css("background-color", "yellow");` here the  class name is `test`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `input[type=radio]:first` selector to select first radio-button in the list.
Or if you want that every gruop first radio button get selected you can use

```
$('element').each(function(){
    $('input[type=radio]:first', this).attr('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For check the first radio button as default you can use the below code

```
$('#pBody').find('input:radio').first().prop({checked:true});
```

or

```
$('#pBody').find('input:radio').first().attr({checked:true});
```

and for checkboxes use

```
$('#pBody').find('input:checkbox').first().prop({checked:true});
```

or

```
$('#pBody').find('input:checkbox').first().attr({checked:true});
```

Comment: I am sure your codes are correct, but it doesn't work after this code $('#pBody input').val(''); I used theme in a function like this:   $('#pBody input').val('');
$('#pBody').find('input:radio').first().attr({ checked: true });

Comment: Are you tried in prop values... I'm too met the same problem so that i was give both 'attr' and 'prop'